# Trying to use EnableCdn with ScriptManager, not fully working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

You can see in the source of this site that some asp.net script files are being served from the microsoft cdn, while a couple others are not: http://www.deadlywind.com .

I'm currently using this in the root master file:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true" 
    EnableCdn="true" 
    LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false"
    ID="ScriptManager1" 
    CompositeScript-ScriptMode="Release" />
```

On the site I have debug mode turned off in the web.config.

(adding clarification)

It appears that the Microsoft Ajax javascript files are still being served up by my server and not the CDN, via the scriptresource.axd references found in the source of the above mentioned website. My question is, why are these not using the CDN and how should I force them to?

Comment: And what exactly is the issue / question that you are referring to? Can you maybe clarify a bit?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure CDN URLs using [WebResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webresourceattribute.aspx) attribute. For example:

```
<Assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("MyScript.js", 
    "application/x-javascript", 
    CdnPath := "http://myCdnServer/js/MyScript.js")>
```

There can be multiple entries and can be put in any code file (as this being an assembly level attribute) but recommended place for keeping these entries would be global.asax.

**EDIT**: additional info requested by OP

In .NET 4.0, if you want to use Microsoft provided scripts from CDN then you don't need to make WebResource entries. `EnableCdn=True` should do the trick but make sure that you are using AJAX Toolkit that supports .NET 4.0 (i.e. Toolkit version 40412). Visit http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx to get more information and list of files on Microsoft CDN.

For .NET 3.5, you have make CDN entries - you can get the script file list from above link and/or actual page source. Folks also uses script combining and then host the combined script on their own CDN for better performance. Check this link: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx

Comment: Ok, but Im actually not sure which scripts are being included. They're not part of my code, they appear to be MS Ajax libs perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will look into these further. One last item- do you think this could be happening due to using the ajaxToolKit:ToolKitScriptManager instead of the asp:scriptmanager? I would expect not but...

Comment: @boomhaur, ToolkitScriptManager inherits from ScriptManager so that shouldn't be an issue but as said, use the the latest version of toolkit for your .NET Fx.

Comment: yes, everything appears to be 4.x... I'll dig some more first though. Seems like such a simple thing.